# TypeScript type errors are ignored

Tags: typescript, systemjs

[Here is SystemJS + TypeScript plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/YASpLYhsF7hhsszRZTV2?p=preview), created from [official Angular plunk template](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5).

As it shows, it ignores all TypeScript type errors, the only thing that is logged to console is `foo`:

*main.ts*

```
const foo: boolean = 'foo';

console.log(foo);
```

*config.js*

```
System.config({
  //use typescript for compilation
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  //typescript compiler options
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
  },
  paths: {
    'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
  },
  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {

    'app': './src',
    ...
  },
  //packages defines our app package
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './main.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    },
    ...
  }
});
```

*index.html*

```
...
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script>
System.import('app')
  .catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
...
```

Generally I would prefer TypeScript to stop application execution and throw type errors.

What is wrong with this setup? Why are TypeScript errors suppressed? How can this setup be changed?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the setup, it's just not that easy to get typechecking in the browser because someone must provide all type definitions required by the compiler in the browser somehow. To sidestep this problem, SystemJS uses `transpileModule()` typescript method which does not do typechecking by design. For 0.19, you can use [plugin-typescript](https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript) and set its `typeCheck` option to true, but starting with SystemJS 0.20 [this is no longer possible](https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript/issues/194). I switched to webpack.

Comment: @artem Thanks, good to know. 0.20 is a show-stopper for several reasons, but probably [there is still hope](https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript/issues/185#issuecomment-275999466) here, I'm not sure. Do you have an idea how the plunk should be updated to use plugin-typescript? [I ended up](https://plnkr.co/edit/xNOvL4efra2IGEUaQxpe?p=info) with `TypeError: AMD module https://unpkg.com/typescript@2.2.1/lib/typescript.js did not define` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [plugin-typescript](https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript/) for SystemJS, which, as of version 6, has the option to enable typechecking in the browser (note that [this option is removed in version 7](https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript/issues/194)).

But you have to confiure that plugin exactly as spelled out in its [readme](https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript/#if-you-are-using-systemjs-without-jspm), that is, have `typescript` package in SystemJS config  with `main` and `meta` like this:

```
typescript: {
  "main": "lib/typescript.js",
  "meta": {
    "lib/typescript.js": {
      "exports": "ts"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, because of this `main`, you have to change `typescript` in the `map` to

```
'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.2.1'
```

Then, you also need to add these to `typescriptOptions`:

```
experimentalDecorators: true,
typeCheck: true
```

After these changes, type errors are being printed in console:

```
unpkg.com/plugin-typescript@6.0.4/lib/plugin.js:498 TypeScript [Error] 
Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. (TS2322)
```

But I don't think there is a way to stop program execution on type errors - `noEmitOnErrors` has no effect for plugin-typescript as far as I can tell.

I saved updated plunk [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/J90fUykSNMGY58dS8SuO?p=preview), no idea how long it will stay.

Comment: I appreciate this a lot. Works like a charm. I've forked the working plunk to https://plnkr.co/edit/hzHAddtsCJZAZkMRRtHS?p=preview , in the case you're willing to delete it.